# How do I select a row and update it in Java?

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm trying to write a BankingApp with database connectivity. Right now, I'm struggling to update the balance of an user. The user inputs the amount he deposits and then the balance is taken from the database and the amount is added onto it, that's at least how I thought.

I will show what I tried.

EDIT: I put a second PreparedStatement and executed the second query with that statement but it is still not working.

```
public void deposit(){

            System.out.println("How much money do u want to deposit?");
            int val = sc.nextInt();
            try {
                String query = "SELECT Balance FROM accounts.accs where AccountNumber =" + 654321 + "";
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
                PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                while (rs.next()){
                    int balance = rs.getInt("Balance");
                    System.out.println("test");
                    int updatedBalance = balance+val;
                    System.out.println("the updatetbalance is" + updatedBalance +"");
                    String query2 = "UPDATE accs" +
                            "SET Balance = " + updatedBalance +"" +
                            "WHERE AccountNumber =" + 654321 +"";
                    PreparedStatement stmt2 = con.prepareStatement(query);
                    stmt2.executeUpdate(query2);
                    con.commit();
                }
```

The updatedBalance shows correct in the console, but it doesn't update in the database. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't re-use the statement object, create a new `PreparedStatement` for the update  query.

Comment: Also `con.commit()` to commit the database transaction.

Comment: I created another PrepareStatement as u suggested and executed the second query with that statement and put in con.commit in the end of the while loop, but still not working  out .

Comment: @xtratic By default connections are in auto-commit

Comment: Please learn how to properly use prepared statements. You should not concatenate values into a query string, but use parameters instead. In this case it will no cause problems because these are integers, but in general it is an unsafe practice.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel So then I can delete the con.commit() line I guess, any suggestions how I can make this work? I Created a second PreparedStatement as suggested and executed the update query with that statement but still not working

Comment: I'd suggest leaving the commit in, and disabling auto-commit instead. And update your question with the code of your current attempt.

Comment: How do I disable auto-commit, dont know about that, what does the con.commit statement do? Will update now

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Oh right, I forgot auto-commit is the default.. yick.

Comment: @yassoplaya you can disable auto-commit with `con.setAutoCommit(false);` just after you've gotten your connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing: **do not use concatenation** for inputting parameters. It's prone to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Second: which DBMS are you using? This update can be done with a single query using *update-from-select* statement. The syntax can differ from database to database, so I'm not going to give you an example of it, but you should definitely consider using this option. You may look up for it in your database documentation.

And finally, here's the code that uses two `PreparedStatement` that should work for you:

```
public void deposit() throws SQLException {

    System.out.println("How much money do u want to deposit?");
    int val = sc.nextInt();
    int accountNumber = 654321;

    String query = "SELECT Balance FROM accounts.accs where AccountNumber = ?";
    try( Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
         PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query)) {

        stmt.setInt(1, accountNumber);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        String query2 = "UPDATE accs " +
                    "SET Balance = ? " +
                    "WHERE AccountNumber = ?";
        try (PreparedStatement stmt2 = con.prepareStatement(query2)) {
            while (rs.next()){
                int balance = rs.getInt("Balance");
                System.out.println("test");
                int updatedBalance = balance+val;
                System.out.println("the updatetbalance is" + updatedBalance +"");

                stmt2.setInt(1, updatedBalance);
                stmt2.setInt(2, accountNumber);
                stmt2.executeUpdate();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there not only one PreparedStatement or do I see it wrong? I am using MySQL.

Comment: Yes, made a mistake. Updated the code. Try it again.

Comment: Now the while loop is not even executed, it is not printing out the updated value. So it does not find any records for that select I guess

Comment: Is account number `654321` present in the database? Do you get any error?

Comment: Yea it is present.

Comment: Well, I dont see a problem in the code above. Try executing the query separately and see if it's working.

Comment: Ok it worked, but how I can undetstand this ? What does the try with the brackets meean, I dont know that try syntax

Comment: It's a try-with-resources statement. You can read about it here: [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: As I understand it just automatically close the objects, when they are not needed anymore, so this is not necessary,  right ? And if it it not necessary why did my code not work?

Comment: Yes, it's not necessary. It's more like a syntax sugar. There were at least two reasons why your code *might* not work: 1. misusing `PreparedStatement` (`stmt.executeQuery(query);` instead of `stmt.executeQuery();`) 2. The lack of spaces in the `update` statement

Comment: Okay it was literally the lack of spaces and the only use of one PreparedStatement, thanks for the help Sir.